# How to set up a cron task in Plesk every 15 minutes?

Tags: cron, task, plesk

I'm a total newbie with Plesk, and I'm wondering how to set up a cron task for executing http address, which is updating profiles. I have my link of course, and I want to run this link every 15 minutes, 24 hours a day, non-stop.

I'd be very glad if you guys could help me with that.

Here's my cron task configuration for root:

[image: cron task configuration]

What should I fill in minute, hour, day? And how about command?

Thanks for helping me,
Mike

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not quite clear what do you mean under "executing http address"

But you can try this setting

Since Plesk **12.5** there are task options:

[image: plesk cron job scheduling task]

In Plesk 12 and below:

[image: plesk 12.0 cron task setup]