# How to set crone job for parallels panel

Tags: php, cron, parallels

I am trying to set a crone job for my site. I have tried several commands to execute a php file located at my live website, but unfortunately none of them work.

```
GET http://www.domain.com/file.php
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.domain.com/file.php
php -q /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/shop/file.php
env php -q /var/www/vhosts/site.ca/httpdocs/croneFile.php
```

Ref Link :

[Parallels forum](http://forum.sp.parallels.com/threads/how-to-use-cronjobs-to-execute-a-php-file.283297/)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499719/how-to-set-up-a-cron-task-in-plesk-every-15-minutes)

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Is this A local file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this : wget -q -O "http://www.domain.com/file.php",
Befor that check file permissions (644 or 755)