# Plesk Panel Scheduled Task

Tags: asp.net, plesk

I want to create scheduled task in plesk panel. I'll run .aspx file. How I create scheduled task? What should i write command textbox in the plesk panel?

Thank You!

Comment: Also please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499719/how-to-set-up-a-cron-task-in-plesk-every-15-minutes/23500171#23500171

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can set that with the following executable file.

```
Path to executable file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
    Arguments: -c "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://domain.test/script.aspx')
```

Also, Please check : https://kb.plesk.com/en/115292

Answer (score 0):

What works for me was to create a vbs file that receives a url and plesk executes that file sending the parameter, an easy solution to all my scheduled tasks

Save the following code in the notepad and save it as .vbs in some path of your server

```
Sub ejecutarTarea()

   Dim oXMLHttp,url

   on error resume next

   Set oXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

   url = WScript.Arguments(0)

   oXMLHttp.open "GET", url, false
   oXMLHttp.send()

   Set oXMLHttp = nothing
End Sub

Call ejecutarTarea()
```

Path to executable file: C:\SomeRoute\File.vbs

Arguments: "http://domain/page.aspx"